# Getting overlapping regex matches in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the regex `1(0*)1` and the test string `1000010001`

I want to have 2 matches, but I find that only 1 gets found :

```
var regex = new Regex("1(0*)1");
var values = regex.Matches(intBinaryString);
// values only has 1 match
```

regexonline seems to agree : https://regex101.com/r/3J9Qxj/1

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already selecting the 1 in front of the second zero by the first match.

```
100001 0001
^^^^^^
```

This is the first match. The rest is just `0001` which does not match your regex.

---

You can circumvent this behavior if you are using lookaheads/lookbehinds:

```
(?<=1)(0*)(?=1)
```

[Live example](https://regex101.com/r/3J9Qxj/2)

---

Because you cannot use lookbehinds in JavaScript, it is enough to only use one lookahead, to prevent the overlapping:

```
1(0*)(?=1)
```

[Live example](https://regex101.com/r/3J9Qxj/3)

---

*And a hint for your [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/3J9Qxj/1) example: You did not add the global flag, which prevents more than one selection.*

Answer (score 4):

You need to match overlapping strings.

It means you should wrap your pattern with a capturing group (`(` + *your pattern* + `)`) and put this consuming pattern into a positive lookahead, then match all occurrences and grab Group 1 value:

```
(?=(YOUR_REGEX_HERE))
```

Use

```
var regex = new Regex("(?=(10*1))");
var values = regex.Matches(intBinaryString)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3D%2810*1%29%29&i=1000010001)

[image]