# Regex Matches in the Middle of Repeated Matches

Tags: c#, regex

Let me explain this case since I tried to search this online already but I couldn't find the same case with this.

I have this binary number:

```
1011010110110
```

I am trying to find matches using this number:

```
101
```

Using this code:

```
Regex.Matches(result, "101").Count
```

This would return 3. But if you will look closely, the right answer should be 4.

**Since there are 4 times you can find 101 on 1011010110110**:

```
(101)1010110110
101(101)0110110
10110(101)10110
10110101(101)10
```

How should I write my Regex so that this will return 4 results or any approach you can advise me to achieve what I am trying to do.

Comment: `Regex.Matches(s, "(?=101)")`

Comment: might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320448/overlapping-matches-in-regex

Comment: Perfect @WiktorStribiżew. What does ?= means by the way?

Comment: `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead.

Comment: Thanks again, if I can just accept your answer. I really appreciate it! @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Yeah, you need not accept it, just upvote [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41989091/3832970) since it turned out helpful for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Done! Thanks again! :)