# .Net get all regex matches (not just the first one)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I'm missing something obvious. I want to use a pattern like `"\d{7}"`, and, for an input of "`12345678`", get matches of "`1234567`" and "`2345678`".

It's gotta be easy, right?

C# or VB.Net. Thanks!

Per suggestions, I tried the following code, to no avail (g.ToString is blank each time):

```
Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?=\d{7})")
Dim m As MatchCollection = r.Matches("12345678")
For each g As match In m
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Match is {0}", g.ToString))
Next
```

Comment: Use `Regex.Matches()` which returns a `MatchCollection` with `Group` objects. You can then iterate the `MatchCollection`. The first `Group` on each `Match` will be the full match, with subsequent `Group` objects being any sub-captures. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41989091/3832970).

Comment: @Charleh, that will not work, as Regex.Matches() on its own will not produce overlapping matches...

Comment: Another duplicate question that might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320448/overlapping-matches-in-regex

Comment: @elgonzo yeah missed that part of the q, thought it was just "how to use Regex to get multiple matches" rather than "how to match multiple times in the same string"

Comment: But to be fair, the regex used is already attempting to do this - it's just not right :)

Comment: So the issue is probably that you are already matching 3 times but you are using a non-capturing assertion - try something like `(?=(\d{7}))` which will place the capture in subgroup 1 for example

Comment: @Charleh I updated my sample code with the suggestion (?=(\d{7})) but the outcome is the same. Matchcollection "m" has two matches, but they both report blank when `g.ToString` is called.

Comment: Yes, because the matches themselves will be blank but the second group in each match (group 1) will be the subcapture which will hold the value. `Match.ToString` will always give you group 0 which for a noncapturing lookahead will not match anything and will return a blank.

Comment: Try it here: http://regexstorm.net/tester - I can clearly see it working (look at the `Table` tab after putting my suggested regex tweak/your numerical string in) - e.g. http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3d%28%5cd%7b7%7d%29%29&i=12345678

Comment: @Charleh nailed it! The observation about the subcapture is the part I was missing. Thank you * 10^6

Comment: No problem, + the 10^6 made me laugh!